# Conditionally run it() block or nest it() block in Webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to have a test in **Webdriver.io** stop when the first **it()** block fails its assertion. Is it possible to either nest **it()** blocks or conditionally execute them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your **first question** "I am trying to have a test in Webdriver.io stop when the first it() block fails its assertion", here is the answer:-

You can use mocha 'bail' option as described here [Mocha Bail](https://mochajs.org/#-bail-b)

Command line usage :-

```
 --bail, -b                 Abort ("bail") after first test failure   [boolean]
```

And, In any configuration file like this

```
"bail" : true 

Any "boolean" flag (which doesn't require a parameter, such as --bail), can be specified using a boolean value, e.g.: "bail": true.
```

For your **second question** on conditional execution of it statements, please see the below code

```
describe("Some module", function() {
if(false) {
    it ("should NOT run this test case", function() { });
}

it("should run this test case", function() { });  });
```

Please let me know if you need more help with this.